# Redirect site in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We have our LMS hosted on shared hosting server.

Our main domain is exampletraining.com

Our public_html folder has following folders inside it:

- cgi-bin
- lms
- moodle
- .htaccess

We added following lines to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampletraining.com/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampletraining.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !lms/
RewriteRule (.*) /lms/$1 [L]
```

so that exampletraining.com should always show the content of exampletraining.com/lms

But our problem is that now we are unable to access exampletraining.com/moodle

What should we change in our .htaccess file so that we can also access exampletraining.com/moodle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an exception for `moodle`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampletraining\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(lms|moodle)/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) lms/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Many thanks! That worked like a charm.
Meanwhile, can you explain a little what exception was added for moodle?
What if I'll add more folders like moodle1, moodle2 so on. What needs to be changed then?

Comment: This line is for handling folder that are skipped for this rule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(lms|moodle)/ [NC]`. You can just add more folders into this condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(lms|moodle|moodle1|moodle2)/ [NC]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]
---
```

Within an htaccess file, the scope of the `<Files>` directive only applies to that directory (I guess to avoid confusion when rules/directives in the htaccess of subdirectories get applied superceding ones from the parent).

So you can have:

```
<Files "log.txt">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

In an htaccess file in your inscription directory. Or you can use mod_rewrite to sort of handle both cases deny access to htaccess file as well as log.txt:

RewriteRule /?.htaccess$ - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^/?inscription/log.txt$ - [F,L]